# CSS Background Color Not Showing

Tags: css, html

I have an HTML5 page built and the image is over-riding the background color in the entire page. I am trying to make the image show up in the background, while the background color shows up in the page that is on top of the background. Copy and paste my code to see for yourself. How do I fix this? Thank you in advance.

This is the index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<h1><img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Logo" width="619" height="117"></h1>

<div id="nav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>

<div id="content">

<img src="windingroad.jpg" alt="Winding Road" width="333" height="156" align="right">

<ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
</ul>

<div>
    12312 Main Street<br>
    Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
    1-888-555-5555
</div>

<br>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Copyright &copy; 2013 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
    <a href="mailto:zhawkins9468@gmail.com">zhawkins9468@gmail.com</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body { background-color: #FFFFCC;
      color: #330000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
      background-image: url(background.gif); }

h1 { background-color: #CCAA66;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center; }

h2 { background-color: #CCAA66;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px; }

img { border: none; }

#nav { text-align: center; }

#footer { background-color: #CCAA66;
         color: #000000;
         font-size: .60em;
         font-style: italic;
         text-align: center; 
         padding: 10px; }

#wrapper { background-color: ffffcc;
           width: 80%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto; 
           min-width: 700px; 
           -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e; 
           -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e; }

#content { padding: 25px; }

.details { padding-left: 20%; 
           padding-right: 20%; }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the image isn't letting the background color through? That only happens with images with transparency and .jpg images don't have transparency.

Comment: I don't think I can follow you

Comment: @DamienBlack - No, the page should look like it's on top of the background. There is a drop shadow on the right and bottom side of the part that should be the page color. The image should look like it is behind it all.

Comment: Just to note so no one gets confused from the comments, in the code above he is using a .gif file as a background image, which can have transparency.

Comment: @Andy - The background image is located in the body selector of the CSS file. The background color that I think should be on top of the image is located in the id #wrapper also located in the CSS file.

Comment: Try playing with the z-index if you are looking at the stacking order. Putting a z-index in the css determines what is on top of what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you provided, Chrome's Inspector reports "ffffcc" as an invalid property value for background-color in the div #wrapper.

Adding the "#" in front of "ffffcc" makes the background-color valid, which would cause it to display correctly instead of the body background-image. Sorry if that doesn't fix the problem, but it's worth a try just in case.

Comment: Nice find, brother! That fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! I've accidentally omitted that little '#' so many times. Glad that solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a typo in your code. You have:

```
#wrapper { background-color: FFFFCC; }
```

Should be:

```
#wrapper { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is the fix. I at least gave you a one up since I had to give the answer to Jack B since he said it first. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks! I gave you one up too. :)